# How do i make javascript communicate with python?

Tags: javascript, python

Right now i'm creating a grammar checker for chrome extension. I will host this program locally, so i want to send the data directly to the python from javascript. I tried the codes from youtube but it won't work.

this is my javascript code :

```
const spawner = require('child_process').spawn;

const data_to_pass_in = {
    data_sent : 'Send this to python script',
    data_returned: undefined
}

console.log('Data sent to python script:', data_to_pass_in);

const python_process = spawner('python', ['./test.py', JSON.stringify(data_to_pass_in)]);

python_process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('Data received from python script:', JSON.parse(data.toString()));
});

python_process.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('Error received from python script:', data.toString());
});`
```

and my python code :

```
import sys
import json
import ast

data_to_pass_back = 'Send this to node process.'

try:
    #string
    input = sys.argv[1]
    output = data_to_pass_back
    print(output)

    #list
    input = ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1])
    output = input
    output['data_returned'] = data_to_pass_back
    print(json.dumps(output))

    sys.stdout.flush()

except Exception as e:
    print("Error:", e, file=sys.stderr)
    sys.stderr.flush()
    sys.exit(1)`
```

and this is the result when i run the js code :
: ata sent to python script: { data_sent: 'Send this to python script', data_returned: undefined }
Error received from python script: Python

i want the python to send the code back to the javascript.

Comment: Your js code can't run in a browser so it doesn't make sense as a browser extension

Comment: What you need is to setup a rest API in python and then send requests from J's using fetch